# nginx server block not playing nicely - 'server not found'

Tags: nginx, configuration, server, directive

The basic installation is working, on linux mint OS. resolving the domain on 'localhost' confirms that nginx is running.

however, the issue i am running into stems from the generation of my own server block. its very basic:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from alias.
        server_name tokum.com www.tokum.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
}
```

as you can see, i have created an alias for www.tokum.com in this server block. attempting to resolve this url in a browser, i am greeted with the lovely 'server not found' message.

my feeling is that it surrounds the 'try_files' functionality, but i cannot be sure why.

No other resources have been created on the server other than my tokum.com server block file, which is located at the path /etc/nginx/sites-available/tokum.com. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Have you added new name to DNS?

Comment: no im unsure as to how to do such a thing. My understanding is that the initial config will route the incoming request to my domain, which is defined in its own server block, and that is all that would be required to return an index.html

Comment: what i mean is - isn't the server_name property the dns name >